# ERROR bash: alias: python.exe' : not found

Tags: python, windows, bash

Every time I start Git Bash I'm getting the same message:

`bash: alias: python.exe' : not found`

(Pay attention to a single quote after python.exe')
It seems to me that after that Git Bash works normally but I cannot figure out why I get this message. My `.bashrc` file has just one line of code:

`alias python='winpty python.exe'`

If use `$ alias` command I have got:

`alias ipython='winpty ipython.exe'`

`alias ll='ls -l'`

`alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'`

`alias python='winpty python.exe'`

Could somebody help me to figure out why I get that strange message?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check that you don't have windows curly quotes but straight quotes?  I try this:

```
# works fine
$ alias python='winpty python.exe'
# does not work fine
$ alias python=‘winpty python.exe’
bash: alias: python.exe’: not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have checked and I use straight quotes in the .bashrc file. This does not solve my problem.

Comment: and if you comment out that line, the issue goes away?

Comment: If I comment out that line, the issue is still there! So, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: In `aliases.sh` file I have found that I used curly quotes. I changed them in straight quotes and fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your help!